# how to build and export next js application with getServerSideProps in it?

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js, export

I am new to next js and I have been trying to build and export my next js application with getServerSideProps in it, but there occurres an error.

Here is my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "npm run build && npm run export"
  },
```

I tried building with `npm run build`,

```
    info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data
info  - Generating static pages (8/8)
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      4.09 kB         102 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B            97.5 kB
├ λ /[id]                                  4.25 kB         102 kB
├ ○ /404                                   495 B            98 kB
├ λ /about                                 780 B          98.3 kB
├ λ /additional                            798 B          98.3 kB
├ ○ /cart                                  2.82 kB         100 kB
├ λ /contact                               1.38 kB        98.9 kB
├ λ /deliver                               796 B          98.3 kB
├ λ /faq                                   792 B          98.3 kB
├ ○ /history                               2.79 kB         100 kB
├ ○ /login                                 1.9 kB         99.4 kB
├ λ /payment                               789 B          98.3 kB
├ ○ /register                              6.76 kB         104 kB
└ ○ /saved                                 2.05 kB        99.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              97.5 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js   42 kB
  ├ chunks/main-a0853fbc3d9f629b.js        25.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-24619101f90696a4.js  28.4 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-a27b2f7f3b9841c4.js     1.51 kB
  └ css/27d177a30947857b.css               194 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

after this I tried `npm run export`, it does the same and doesnt give any `html` file in `out`

Then I tried `next build`, and here is the error of this:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/saved". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at S (C:\Users\User\Desktop\kuba-motors\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js:18:327)
    at exports.useMemo (C:\Users\User\Desktop\kuba-motors\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js:23:109)
    at Provider (C:\Users\User\Desktop\kuba-motors\node_modules\react-redux\lib\components\Provider.js:24:41)
    at d (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:736:46)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:368:51)

info  - Generating static pages (8/8)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /
        /404
        /_error: /500
        /cart
        /history
        /login
        /register
        /saved
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:499:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1015:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:889:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:82:25)
```

Then I tried `next export` and here is the error of this:

```
info  - Exporting (14/14)
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /
        /404
        /[id]
        /about
        /additional
        /cart
        /contact
        /deliver
        /faq
        /history
        /login
        /payment
        /register
        /saved
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:499:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
```

Comment: You can't, `getServerSideProps` is not supported by `next export`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `getServerSideProps` when you create a static export with `next export`. The command `next export` creates a standalone static website (SPA) without a node server as the backbone. That means you cannot run anything on the server. The only time you can talk to a server is at build time with `getStaticProps`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features for more details.